# Accessing submit button which is created for every item in a loop -- HTML jQuery AJAX

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a wishlist page which contains items each having a **remove button** which is created in a **loop** using **form** and each button has item id as value. I want to make a post request whenever a remove button is clicked in order to remove that item from the database.

But the problem is that there are many buttons created in the loop with the same id, so how do I access them individually?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>::WISHLIST::</h1>

    {% for wish in wishes %}
        <img src={{wish.image_path}} width="150" height="200">
        </br>
        {{wish.material}}
        {{wish.productType}}
        </br>
        {{wish.price}}
        </br>
        <form method="POST" target="_self">
            <button id="remove_wish" name="remove_wish" type="submit" value={{wish.id}}>Remove</button>
        </form>
        </br>
    {% endfor %}

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#remove_wish').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert($('#remove_wish').val())
           $.ajax({
            data : {
                    delete_wish : $('#remove_wish').val()
                    },
                type : 'POST',
                url : '/wishlist/',
                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('something went wrong')
                }
            });
        });
        })
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here I tried using the same id, but this only works for the top most item on the wishlist and for others it gives the error: **NoResultFound: No row was found for one()**

Comment: Use `class`. Id must be unique.

Comment: Using `class`  and find element using `this` helps you to  delete.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I am new to jquery and ajax so sorry for the naive question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of alternatives of how could you solve your issue and a tip.

**TIP:**
Remove the `<form>` tag from your **foreach**, otherwise you'll be creating one form per button. The ideal scenario would be having only **one form** and several buttons. Like this:

```
<form method="POST" target="_self">
    {% for wish in wishes %}
        <img src={{wish.image_path}} width="150" height="200">
        </br>
        {{wish.material}}
        {{wish.productType}}
        </br>
        {{wish.price}}
        </br>
        <button id="remove_wish" name="remove_wish" type="submit" value={{wish.id}}>Remove</button>
        </br>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

**ALTERNARTIVE #1 :**
As **@cooper** and **@Shree** already told you, you should get rid of the `id` and use a `class` instead. Now, wrap your button inside a container, a `div` (it could be with an `id` or with a `class`) for example (please notice that this container **must be outside** of your foreach as well). And change the type of your button from `submit` to `button`. Like this:

```
<form method="POST" target="_self">
    <div id="divContainer">
        {% for wish in wishes %}
            <img src={{wish.image_path}} width="150" height="200">
            </br>
            {{wish.material}}
            {{wish.productType}}
            </br>
            {{wish.price}}
            </br>
            <button class="remove_wish" type="button" data-wishid={{wish.id}} >Remove</button>
            </br>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</form>

//and then you can manage all your buttons click events like this
$("#divContainer").on("click", "remove_wish", function() {
    var id = $(this).data('wishid');
    //the rest of your code
});
```

**ALTERNARTIVE #2 :**
Or even easier, you can use the `onclick` event and pass your `id` to a function. Like this:

```
<form method="POST" target="_self">
    {% for wish in wishes %}
        <img src={{wish.image_path}} width="150" height="200">
        </br>
        {{wish.material}}
        {{wish.productType}}
        </br>
        {{wish.price}}
        </br>
        <button type="button" onclick="removeWish(" + {{wish.id}} +")" >Remove</button>
        </br>
    {% endfor %}
</form>

//and outside your $(document).ready(function()
function removeWish(id) {
    //the rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have more than one element in the DOM with the same id.

Change in your button the next things:

- Add a class to the buttons. Let's say *remove_wish*.
- Change the id value of the buttons to *wish-{{wish.id}}* (for example).

`<button class="remove_wish" id="wish-{{wish.id}}" name="remove_wish" type="submit"` `value={{wish.id}}>Remove</button>`

In your AJAX call, change the selector of the event for listening to the class selector instead of the id selector:

```
$('.remove_wish')
```

Get the id of your element using the [substring function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp):

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var id_value = id.substring(5); //five because "wish-" has five characters.
```

I think this should do the work.

Comment: The value can be accessed directly by: `var val = $(this).val()`

Comment: @RaghavMaheshwari, yes, sure. I didn't aware of that.